# Time Series and Prediction in R

Tags: r, datetime, machine-learning

Sorry if this question seems so basic but the examples I see online are too complex for a beginner like me so please help me through this. Basically, I want to predict when is a `Measurement` high and low based on the data. Below is a part of the dataset I have. The full picture is a **10-day with 30-minute interval**.

```
       Datetime            Measurement
1    4/4/2013 11:59              0.532
2    4/4/2013 12:29              0.647
3    4/4/2013 12:59              0.564
4    4/4/2013 13:29              0.425
5    4/4/2013 13:59              0.253
```

I tried the following to convert the `Datetime` column to a `Datetime` type

```
data$Datetime <- strptime(x = as.character(data$Datetime),
                                 format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

which resulted to

```
           Datetime            Measurement
1   2013-04-04 11:59:00              0.532
2   2013-04-04 12:29:00              0.647
3   2013-04-04 12:59:00              0.564
4   2013-04-04 13:29:00              0.425
5   2013-04-04 13:59:00              0.253
```

I've stumbled upon [this](http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/complete-tutorial-time-series-modeling/) and maybe it's necessary to convert the `data frame` to a `time series`. I tried the `ts` and `xts` but I think I'm going nowhere. I also tried

```
library(timeSeries)
as.timeSeries(data)
```

but then it says `data.frame` after I performed `class(data)`.

How can I **convert** it to a `time series` given the situation? Can I make the link my basis and will the **ARIMA** model make sense? Or are there simpler and reasonable **time series analysis algorithms** out there that can be done?

Please and thank you very much.